# How's allowing Many access specifier in a class useful for machine-generated code

Tags: c++, class

I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup book, "The C++ programming language, 4th Edition".

I came across a section in which the following code was written.

```
class Date4 { 
    public: Date4(int dd, int mm, int yy); 
    private: int d, m, y; 
    public: void add_year(int n); 
};
```

Then, he made a remark which I don't really understand.

"However,  allowing many access specifiers in a class is useful for machine-generated code."

Does it mean it improves performance or something else is happening beneath the hood?.

Comment: Consider a script that generates C++ source files (containing classes), it's easier to write than if each access specifier had to only appear once. You don't have to "sort" the members before emitting them.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That is useful to the developer, what about machine-generated code?

Comment: The C++ source file **is** the machine generated code. The machine executes the script.

Comment: While a human developer might sort the code by subjects like e.g. the public interface, the protected overriders, the private internal stuff, e.g. a [transpiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) might generate c++ code out of another language. While the human developer might need `public:`, `protected:`, `private:` only once in a class (and would for a nice style), the transpiler might prefix even every member by an access specifier without any impact to semantics or performance. I guess this is what Mr. Stroustrup intended to emphasize.